# How to pass username and password in a shell script using java

Tags: java, shell

I have a shell script. Now I want to pass `NAME` and `PASS` in this script using java. Then I want to execute it using `java`. Below I have written here my `shell` script as well as java code.

Please help me out.

```shell
#!/bin/bash

# Create ftp user, create folders and set permissions
# Usage: ./create_ftp_user.sh [username] "[password]"
#

NAME=bimal
PASS=bimal

echo "USAGE: create_ftp_user.sh [username] [password]"

# check input parameters
if [ -z "$NAME" ]; then
    echo "Error: username is not set"
    exit
fi

if [ -z "$PASS" ]; then
    echo "Error: password not set"
    exit
fi

# create system user
echo "Creating user: $NAME"
echo "With password: $PASS"

useradd -p `openssl passwd -1 $PASS` -m $NAME -g ftpaccess -s /usr/sbin/nologin

# save to users log
echo "user: $NAME, pass: $PASS" >> new_ftp_users_list

# add user to ftp daemon list
echo "$NAME" >> /etc/vsftpd/chroot_list

# create user ftp dir
mkdir /var/ftpupload/$NAME

# Set Ownership
chown $NAME: /var/ftpupload/$NAME

# Set permissions
chmod 0777 /var/ftpupload/$NAME

# restart vsftp daemon
#/etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testscript;

/**
 *
 * @author deepak
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException;

public class TestScript {
    int iExitValue;
    String sCommandString;

    public void runScript(String command){
        sCommandString = command;
        CommandLine oCmdLine = CommandLine.parse(sCommandString);
        DefaultExecutor oDefaultExecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
        oDefaultExecutor.setExitValue(0);
        try {
            iExitValue = oDefaultExecutor.execute(oCmdLine);
        } catch (ExecuteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("Execution failed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("permission denied.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        TestScript testScript = new TestScript();
        testScript.runScript("gksudo sh /home/deepak/Desktop/ftpusers.sh");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the question here how to pass the username and password as arguments to the shell script from the java script that calls it?

Comment: @ Etan Reisner , Yes..

Comment: aren't you hardcoding your values? `NAME=bimal
PASS=bimal`

Comment: Simple i wrote shell script and execute with java code..
now i want to pass username and password using java in shell script and then want to execute using java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CommandLine` can be used to set shell arguments:

```
CommandLine oCmdLine = new CommandLine(sCommandString);
oCmdLine.addArgument("bimal");
oCmdLine.addArgument("bimalPassword");
```

You can refer various options on [Apache CommandLine](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/commandline.html) documentation page.

Once done, the arguments will be available in shell script as $1 and $2 *positional shell parameters*:

```
NAME=$1
PASS=$2
```

Comment: i did not understand.